# Unix permissions of subdirectories

Tags: unix, ubuntu, file-permissions

I have two users (userA and userB) who are in the same group (sharedGroup). userA creates a folder `sharedFolder` in his own directory, and changes the permission so that userB should be able to 'see' it (RW access).

`ls -al /homer/userA/sharedFolder` by userA:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 userA sharedGroup 4096 Jan 20 11:41 .
-rw-rw-r-- 1 userA sharedGroup 2559 Jan 20 11:04 testFile
```

Why can't userB access the folder or the files from outside?

```
cat /home/userA/sharedFolder/testFile
```

fails with `Permission Denied`.

**My questions**

- Is it true, that you can't access a directory if you don't have read
  access of the parent directory?
- Could somebody link me to the
  documentation or help me out?
- Is there an alternative without moving
  'sharedFolder' out of userA's home directory?

Comment: You may find [this post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true, that you can't access a directory if you don't have read access of the parent directory?

False. You need the EXECUTE perm.
(read is for directory listing, a.k.a "ls")

> Could somebody link me to the documentation or help me out?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

> Is there an alternative without moving 'sharedFolder' out of userA's home directory?

Add "x" to any directory parent to the file/directory you're willing to share. You would like to create a ~/pub/ to avoid exposing all your files... and be aware that any "." file in your directory COULD be read if you did not take care of permissions.

i.e : do ls -al to check this out.

Comment: oh perfect, that's what I missed! Thank you so much.